# How to read byte array of AKMicrophone

Tags: swift, audiokit

My project currently uses `AudioKit` to manipulate the audio recording side. Today I am able to use the `AKAmplitudeTracker` for the amplitude and it's working fine.

I was trying to attach a tap to get a determined range of bytes to send using UDP to a server but I don't know how to do it. Any idea?

```
AKAudioFile.cleanTempDirectory()
AKSettings.bufferLength = .medium
AKSettings.defaultToSpeaker = true

mic = AKMicrophone()

guard let unwrappedMic: AKMicrophone = self.mic else {
  return
}

fft = AKFFTTap(unwrappedMic)
amplitudeTracker = AKAmplitudeTracker(unwrappedMic)

guard let unwrappedAmplitudeTracker: AKAmplitudeTracker = self.amplitudeTracker else {
  return
}

// Turn the volume all the way down on the output of amplitude tracker
let noAudioOutput = AKMixer(unwrappedAmplitudeTracker)
noAudioOutput.volume = 0

AudioKit.output = noAudioOutput
AudioKit.start()
```

-

Could it be done using a limit of buffer size to get this value flushed and delegates?

Thank you.

Comment: You're on the right track look at the AudioKit taps for tracking, analysis, and graphing.  Your tap will gather the bytes and will have to manage how it doles them out to the UDP server. I think your question is a bit too broad "how do you do it" - write some code based on the taps and see how far you get, and then come back with a more specific question.

Comment: I only see `AKFFTTap` and `AKAmplitudeTap` on the documentation, which one I need to use? If it's `AKFFTTap`, do I need to do it manually?

Comment: I would like to get the FFT data array when it reaches a determined size (maybe 512 bytes?) and flush it to a file.

Comment: Do I need to use the function `fft(_ fft: EZAudioFFT!, updatedWithFFTData fftData: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>, bufferSize: vDSP_Length)` to reach it, creating a EZAudioFFT with a listener and reading the updatedWithFFTData pointer?

Comment: @AureliusProchazka Any idea? Sorry but have you received my message? :p

Comment: @AureliusProchazka Maybe this? It was a little bit hard to find. https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/tree/aa349f98f5d26254ca7fee75f02f915a861cd98d/AudioKit/Common/Taps/Lazy%20Tap

Comment: Would you recommend to use `AKLazyTap` or `AKRenderTap` for lazy write on storage?

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar; create a circular buffer of the last _n_ seconds of audio, which will periodically be rendered to disk based on user responses (basically, liking what they hear). What solution did you end up using? AKRenderTap?